# Are humans on Barsoom/Mars the same species as Earth's humans?

Tags: john-carter

As it was noted [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17846/have-there-been-other-humans-on-barsoom-mars), some of Barsoom's population really look like Earth's humans.

Is there a link between Earth's human population and Mars? Are humans originally from Mars and then populated Earth, or is it the other way around and they came from Earth and populated Mars? Or are they two completely different species that evolved separately and it's a coincidence that they look the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the humanoids on Barsoom lay eggs - even the Red Men - so it is unlikely they are related, despite the outward similarities.

Strangely, John Carter is able to reproduce with Dejah Thoris despite this. There are no details on how this was achieved...

Comment: "There are no details on how this was achieved..." I'd watch that.

Comment: The Red People do have quite a bit of sophisticated technology, some they created, others they inherited from an earlier species. Perhaps it was used to facilitate offspring between the two humanoid species.